# É um problema eu trabalhar somente com leitura de um arquivo com ele aberto em modo escrita e leitura?

Tags: c, desempenho, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou começando a trabalhar com arquivos em C e preciso fazer o esqueleto de um programa de cadastro de livros, salvando as informações em um arquivo. A minha dúvida é se devo trabalhar com os arquivos assim, abrindo o arquivo no inicio do programa e fechando no fim:

```
int main(){     
    int aux=0, menu;
    FILE *acervo;

    acervo = fopen("acervo.txt", "a+");    

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf ("O que você quer fazer? \n 1 – Inserir um novo cadastro \n 2 – Mostrar todos os cadastros \n 0 – Encerrar \n");
        scanf ("%d", &menu);

        if( menu == 1){
            cadastroLivro();                
        } else if (menu == 2){              
            printf("Aqui mostra os dados cadastrados (não está pronto). \n");                                   
        } else if(menu != 0) {          
            printf("Erro: opção inválida! \n");     
        }           
    } while (menu != 0);        
    fclose(acervo);     
}
```

Ou assim, abrindo e fechando a cada tarefa:

```
int main(){     
    int aux=0, menu;
    FILE *acervo;

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf ("O que você quer fazer? \n 1 – Inserir um novo cadastro \n 2 – Mostrar todos os cadastros \n 0 – Encerrar \n");
        scanf ("%d", &menu);

        if( menu == 1){
            acervo = fopen("acervo.txt", "a");
            cadastroLivro();
            fclose(acervo);    
        } else if (menu == 2){
            acervo = fopen("acervo.txt", "r");
            printf("Aqui mostra os dados cadastrados (não está pronto). \n");
            fclose(acervo);    
        } else if(menu != 0) {          
            printf("Erro: opção inválida! \n");   
        }    
    } while (menu != 0);
}
```

Entendo que a primeira opção deixa uma margem maior para que o arquivo se corrompa, principalmente quando quero apenas ler ele e ele está permitindo a escrita, mas a segunda faça com que o "programa" fique mais lento, então não sei qual a melhor prática aqui.

Comment: Em tudo isso, depende, sem contexto não dá para dizer.

Comment: Tentei dar o contexto.. o que faltou?

Comment: Onde está o contexto?

Comment: A ideia de seu programa é que ele seja iniciado no início do dia e permaneça em execução até de noite ou seja executado apenas quando se fizer necessário e encerrado tão logo seja executada a opção? A resposta determinará se é mais aconselhável abrir uma vez e fechar ao final ou abrir e fechar a cada opção escolhida. Creio que seu programa ficará mais lento apenas com um número extremamente grande de aberturas e fechamentos do arquivo, não creio que seja algo significativo com poucos milhares de operações.

Comment: É só um trabalho, pra ser aberto só quando o professor rodar o código xD Mas se posso colocar na casa dos milhares então acho que abrir e fechar a cada ação seria uma prática melhor nesse caso, já que mesmo que eu imagine uma situação onde esse programa seria efetivamente usado, não chegaria a casa das mil requisições em um dia...

Comment: @ThaviLang A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Essas decisões dependem do contexto real. Eu sei que todo mundo quer uma decisão mágica que sirva para tudo, mas não pode ser assim, se fosse não precisaria de programadores, todos problemas já teriam sido resolvidos.

Para este caso tanto faz a escolha que fizer porque é um exercício que não tem requisitos reais sobre isso. Em outros casos cada detalhe do requisito pode fazer diferença. Por isso que sempre digo que requisitos artificias não são bons para ajudar aprender resolver problemas, eles servem só para forçar determinados mecanismos específicos serem usados, e nem da maneira certa, mas só que esteja legalmente certo do ponto de vista da linguagem.

Apesar de que qualquer um sirva muito bem ao propósito, por ser um exercício e muito simples eu prefiro o código que não repete, então o primeiro parece muito melhor. Pra falar a verdade não faço ideia porque fez o segundo, ele pode ser interessante em algum caso muito específico, que não é o apresentado, e o caso específico provavelmente nem poderia fazer diferente.

Vendo esse código eu me preocupo mais com outras coisas do que com isso.

Comment: Se você apontar os outros problemas que vê eu ficaria feliz também.. :)

Comment: E sobre o porque fiz a segunda, entendo que nesse caso em específico não tenha grande relevância, mas estava tentando pensar em uma situação real, o que seria o indicado.

Comment: Eu respondi sua pergunta, os erros não são graves. Conforme eu disse, uma situação tem especificidades reais que devem ser consideradas, no caso não tem nada real, só uma possível especulação que só você sabe, por isso eu nem queria responder a pergunta, eu só posso responder o que foi perguntado, não o que talvez seria bom em outro caso real que ninguém sabe qual. Um caso real esse código seria absurdamente diferente, tudo o que se aprende por aí em C não é como se programa de verdade em projetos reais.